# How does the compiler knows that a second destructor has to be called, for an object constructed twice, at the same address?

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor, placement-new

In the code that follows, the object `sub` in class `C` is constructed twice. The first construction calls the default ctor `Sub()` and the second construction uses `placement new`  to reconstruct this object in the same address.

Therefore the destructors are also called twice. The first call uses the direct call to the `Sub` dtor in `~C()` and the second call is invoked after the end of `main()`, I believe, by the `atexit()` function.

Given that the object `sub` is reconstructed at the same address, how does the compiler knows that the second destructor must be called after `main()`? Where does he keep this information?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Table
{
    int i;
    Table(int j) : i(j) {}
};

struct Sub
{
    Table* pTable;
    Sub(int j) { cout << "ctor placement new" << endl; pTable = new Table(j); }
    Sub() { cout << "ctor default" << endl; pTable = 0; }
    ~Sub() { if( pTable ) cout << "dtor placement new" << endl;
             else         cout << "dtor default" << endl;
             delete pTable; pTable = 0; }
};

class C
{
    Sub sub;

    public:
    C() { new (&sub) Sub(10); }
    ~C() { (&sub)->~Sub(); }
};

int main()
{
    C c;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this is clearly undefined behavior, if you reason out what's happening, it's pretty obvious.

You create an object of class C.  In that process, the default constructor of Sub is called implicitly. pTable is 0. Then, you explicitly call the int constructor, which initializes pTable.  Then, in the destructor, you explicitly call Sub's destructor. pTable is set to 0 again.  Then, at the end of C's destructor, Sub's destructor is called again, implicitly.

It's not at the end of main that it's happening.  It's happening at the end of C's destructor.

Comment: Where is the undefined behavior ?

Comment: @user1042389: The undefined behavior is in calling a destructor(implicitly in this case) on an already destucted(i.e. no longer valid) object.

Comment: There is no undefined behavior here, since the second call to the constructor was made with a `placement new`. In fact, you are required to call the destructor explicitly in those cases.

Comment: @user1042389: The undefined behavior is not in your call to Sub's destructor.  It was in the implicit call to Sub's destructor at the end of C's destructor.  So, technically, the compiler caused it.  But you forced its hand, since it is required to call the destructor on all sub-objects.

Comment: I believe you're wrong. There is no undefined behavior in this case. The code will run under any compiler.

Comment: @user1042389: That statement proves that you don't know what undefined behavior is.  Undefined behavior means that anything can happen with your code.  It can even appear to run error-free.  That doesn't mean that it's correct.

Comment: C++2003, §12.4 [class.dtor], ¶14: "Once a destructor is invoked for an object, the object no longer exists; the behavior is undefined if the
destructor is invoked for an object whose lifetime has ended (3.8). [Example: if the destructor for an automatic
object is explicitly invoked, and the block is subsequently left in a manner that would ordinarily
invoke implicit destruction of the object, the behavior is undefined. ]"

Comment: @Rob I don't think this applies to an explicit destructor call, since in this case the object will still exist in memory, after destruction. That means, no one will be able to allocate anything on the area reserved for that object, until the second destruction is done, which will finally free the area reserved for the object.

Comment: @user1042389: That's exactly the case that it applies to.  Did you read the example? [Example: if the destructor for an automatic object is explicitly invoked, and the block is subsequently left in a manner that would ordinarily invoke implicit destruction of the object, the behavior is undefined. ]

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I guess you are right, since c an automatic object. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 4):

Your assumption about `atexit()` is incorrect. The destructor for `sub` is called by the destructor for `C` when the object `c` goes out of scope in `main()`.

A C++ destructor *always* calls destructors for all its sub-objects.

Your code is invalid anyway, because you're calling the placement new operator on a chunk of memory (`sub`) that has already been constructed into an object. Similarly to the destructor, a C++ constructor *always* calls constructors for all its sub-objects.

Comment: Why the call for the `placement new` is invalid ? Where does it say that an object cannot be constructed twice at the same address ?

Comment: Perhaps you're unaware of the correct syntax for calling a sub-object constructor with parameters: `C(): sub(10) { }` will call the `Sub::Sub(int)` constructor when `C` is constructed.

Comment: Note that no Table is created in the first constructor call. So there is no memory leak.

Comment: I'm well aware of the syntax you mentioned. I was just experimenting with the `placement new` and the call to an explicit destructor. My point is, this is a valid code, unless someone proves me otherwise.

Comment: Okay, the main reason this is invalid is that the `C::~C()` destructor calls the `Sub::~Sub()` destructor on *memory that has already been destructed*. Maybe it doesn't cause a problem for your compiler, but consider a more complex case such as with virtual methods or even virtual inheritance.

Comment: "Where does it say that an object cannot be constructed twice at the same address ?" -- you need to be told that this is a bad idea? (at least, constructing it twice without an intervening destruction)

Answer (score 0):

When c goes out of scope, its destructor is called. The C destructor will explicitly call the sub destructor. When the C destructor is done, the sub destructor will also be called (again), because all C++ destructors automatically call the destructors of all their internal objects.

Essentially, the code

```
(&sub)->~Sub();
```

is unnecessary, and incorrect. You should never explicitly call the destructor of a managed object.

**Edit:**
It's valid to explicitly call the destructor on an object that was constructed via placement new. However this is only the case when the object is not **managed**. For example:

```
class C
{
    Sub sub[1];

    public:
    C() { new (sub) Sub(10); }
    ~C() { sub->~Sub(); }
};
```

This is not only valid, but necessary because the member of C is of type Sub[1] (or more generally Sub*), so Sub's destructor will not be called explicitly when C is destroyed.

Comment: Since the object `sub` was reconstructed with a call to a `placement new expression`, the explicit destructor call is valid.

Comment: The object sub will still be destructed automatically when c goes out of scope

Answer (score 0):

The other answers make valid points about undefined behavior, but I'm surprised no one's mentioned how this program should be corrected.

`Sub`'s destructor *does* need to be called manually here, but it needs to be called *before the placement new*, not during destruction:

```
class C
{
    Sub sub;

    public:
    C() { 
        (&sub)->~Sub();
        new (&sub) Sub(10); 
    }
};
```

In the current code you create an instance of `C`, which default constructs an instance of `Sub` then *immediately* placement news another instance of `Sub` on top of the old one without calling its destructor. At the end of main `c`'s destructor gets called, which calls `sub`'s destructor explicitly, then `sub`'s destructor gets called again on the already destructed object. Not only is this undefined behavior, if `Sub`'s default constructor allocated you would also have a memory leak.

In the corrected code `sub` is default constructed, destructed manually, constructed via placement new, then destructed implicitly when `c` falls out of scope at the end of main.

So the answer is that the compiler *doesn't* know that the destructor needs to be called when you recreate the object at the same address because placement new doesn't take an *object* as its first parameter, it takes a `void*`. There's no way for it to determine whether that pointer is pointing to an existing object, so you have to call the destructor manually.